# Restore mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to restore MySQL dump created the following way:

```
require_once 'mysql_restore.class.php';
$restore_obj = new MySQL_Restore();

$restore_obj->server = 'localhost';
$restore_obj->username = 'root';
$restore_obj->password = '';
$restore_obj->database = 'database';
if (!$restore_obj->Execute(MSR_FILE, 'bk.sql.gz', true, false))
{
  die($restore_obj->error);
}
```

but its showing an error

**Warning: gzuncompress() [function.gzuncompress]: data error in C:\wamp\www\nidhin\mysql_restore.class.php on line 42
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\nidhin\mysql_restore.class.php on line 215**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think as the error states there may be an mismatch of object type which is passed to the class.. Unless we have a glimpse of the mysql_restore.class.php we can find the bug.. Can you post what the line no 215 exactly contains?

Comment: Hi kvijayahari , its working now , its mistake in the function param order

Answer (score 1):

```
function Execute($param, $mode = MSR_STRING, $is_compressed = false, $split_only = false)
```

You inverted the params order.

It's :

```
!$restore_obj->Execute('bk.sql.gz', MSR_FILE, true, false))
```

Instead of :

```
!$restore_obj->Execute(MSR_FILE, 'bk.sql.gz', true, false))
```